# Nhibernate(Fluent) SchemaExport and SQlite Problem!

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate(Fluent) with Sqlite and it worked with no problems what I have done:

- Create the POCO EntityClasses for each table like this:

  > ```
  > public class tbl_Manufactor : BusinessObject<tbl_Manufactor>
  > {
  >     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  > }
  > ```

The Entity Classes all inherit from BusinessObject which contains the ID Property and simple CRUD functions
I have also other 6 Entity Classes

1. Create the Mappings with FluentHibernate like this:

   > ```
   > using Database.Entitites;
   > using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
   >
   > namespace Database.Mappings
   > {
   >     public class tbl_ManufactorMap : ClassMap<tbl_Manufactor>
   >     {
   >         public tbl_ManufactorMap()
   >         {
   >             Id(x => x.ID);
   >             Map(x => x.Name);
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
2. Create the Fluent Config like this:

> ```
>  var Config = Fluently.Configure()
>             .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard  
>                 .ConnectionString(c=>c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("dbconnection"))  
>                 .ShowSql())  
>             .Mappings(m =>  
>                 m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<tbl_Manufactor>())     
>             .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>  _configuration = cfg)  
>
>             sessionFactory = Config.BuildSessionFactory();
> ```

1. Do a SchemaExport to Create the Schema with:

   > ```
   > new SchemaExport(_configuration)
   >                 .Create(false, true);
   > ```

Then Nhibernate created a fully working SQlite Database with the right tables!

But then I wanted to add 2 entity classes(I have done it in the same way as before) but when I run my test(which created my first database schema) it not add the new classes(tables) to the database!

The craziest thing is, that the test is always deleting any created database and recreate it with SchemaExport every time I run the test.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have the option of using Execute directly for database updates:

```
bool script = false;
bool update = true;
new SchemaExport(_configuration).Execute(script, update);
```

Edit: Make sure the mapping classes are public.

Comment: Not worked too, now i wrote a test to add a new Element of the new class (example: tbl_Employee): var empl = new tbl_Mitarbeiter { Name = "TestEmployee" }; and save. And the test run show me: NHibernate.MappingException : No persister for: Database.Entitites.tbl_Employee
Why?

Comment: Are your mapping classes marked as public? Are they in the same assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite in memory only exists for the life time of the connection. So for each new connection you need to start from the beginning.

I know two solutions for this. One is to only use a single session (and connection) for the unit tests. The other is what I did: I implemented a connection provider which always returns the same connection.

Comment: I use a NHibernateSessionManager singleton class with NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession() method

Answer (score 0):

You could check the following :
 - Are the new entity classes in the same assembly ?
 - Check also for a loop in the model.

Comment: The new entity class is in the same folder as the other classes: ProjectFolder --> Entitites --> Entityclasses. What do mean with loop?

Comment: Months ago Nhibernate refused to create some tables with "ToMany" relations like A -> B -> C -> A.  In some cases of buggy mapping, NHibernate(Fluent) doesn't throw an error and generate only a partial model.